# How to setup container to use with ServiceSTack.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

I am trying to implement Redis caching for the first time

I have downloaded the ServiceStack.Redis libraries in my C# application

I am following the instriuctions here:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis

I am assuming the first step is to create a pool so I tried this

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => 
    new RedisManagerPool(redisConnectionString));
```

How do I setup my container as in container.Register

I read this article around the IoC container but just can wrap my head around this.

Why do I need to create a container and how do I implement it so that I can create my pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have (or want to use) an IOC Container you can just hold a singleton reference to the Redis Pool, e.g:

```
class MyApp
{
   public static IRedisClientsManager RedisManager = new RedisManagerPool(connString);
}
```

Which you can then reference in your code to access a RedisClient, e.g:

```
using (var redis = MyApp.RedisManager.GetClient())
{
    //...
}
```